# SonarQube pl/sql rule plsql:S1764 issue

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

The pl/sql rule plsql:S1764 in SonarQube detects that "Identical expressions should not be used on both sides of a binary operator".

But it checks "/" character as operator.
Then in formula we have false positive:
[image]

If suggest to add "/" in ignored operators (like * and +).

Comment: Not the question I know, but shouldn't `l_secinday` be `86400` (seconds in a day) rather than `.000011574` (days in a second)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed a false positive in SonarPLSQL. I created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLSQL-658) to track this issue and fix it.